# What is the correct syntax to break a PL/SQL procedure call in multiple lines?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus, ora-06550

I am calling a PL/SQL procedure like this:

```
execute util.verify(src_schema => '&username',
                    stab       => '&tab_name');
```

and I get these errors:

```
SQL> execute util.verify(src_schema => '&username',
BEGIN util.verify(src_schema => 'u1',; END;

                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 57: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
date <a string literal with character set specification>
<a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
<an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
<an alternatively


SQL>                   stab       => '&tab_name',
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "stab      ..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Looks like I cannot just break the call in between at a `,`. How can I write this call in multiple lines?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SQLPlus, you put a dash at the end of lines that continues on the next line.

```
execute util.verify(src_schema => '&username', -
                    stab       => '&tab_name');
```

**Update**: Added link to documentation

[EXECUTE, SQL*Plus® User's Guide and Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12022.htm#SQPUG043)

Comment: This is only for SQL*PLUS commands, correct? SQL and PL/SQL commands typed into SQL*PLUS automatically allow continuation to a new line.

Comment: @Shannon, I'm not sure how execute is classified. But sql/dml/ddl works with new lines (but not blank lines).

Answer (score 8):

There is an alternative way, some thing like the below:

```
begin
    util.verify(src_schema => '&username',
                    stab       => '&tab_name');
end;
/
```

Comment: More elegant solution!!

Answer (score 6):

`execute xxxx;` (or `exec xxxx;`) is a short-cut for writing `begin xxxx; end;`

It only works for one liners. So if you have multiple lines, you need to explicitly use `begin` and `end`.

Comment: That was mind blowing. Especially if you try to find description of behavior in extensive Oracle documentation...